# Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php

Here is the code:

```
<? $fields = json_decode($this->item->extra_fields); 
$allowed_fields= array('3','5');  
if ( $fields != NULL ) { 
foreach ( $fields as $field ) { 
if ( in_array($field->id, $allowed_fields ) && $field->value != NULL) {  
?>
<span class = "list_for<? echo $field->id; ?>">
<? echo $field->value;?></span><? }   } }?>
```

When I change json_decode to json_encode I get the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...
----------
```

Everything worked before the upgrade of PHP to 5.4 from 5.3.

I am not a developer so please try to not be too technical. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it already says in the error message, feed it with a **json string**, but instead you fed it with an array

Comment: `$fields` is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that **json_decode** accepts string and according to the above error you are trying to pass an array to it so if you need to iterate on the **fields** array you may want to ignore **json_decode** as it seems that you already have an array.

**json_encode** accepts array but it gives a string so it give you a warning when you try to iterate on sting

so try the below code.

```
<? $fields = $this->item->extra_fields; 
$allowed_fields= array('3','5');  
if ( $fields ) { 
foreach ( $fields as $field ) { 
if ( in_array($field->id, $allowed_fields ) && $field->value != NULL) {  
?>
<span class = "list_for<? echo $field->id; ?>">
<? echo $field->value;?></span><? }   } }?>
```

Answer (score 2):

as stated [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), do it like this

```
$fields = json_decode($this->item->extra_fields, true);
```

When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

$fields will be an array and the `foreach()` will work

Comment: Was just about to answer this myself, good answer and should keep the rest of the code working

Comment: inside the foreach he uses field as an object, he will have to rewrite it if changing to an assoc array.

Comment: I added the true bit, but I still get the original error message.

Comment: exactly what is in '$this->item->extra_fields', what do you get when you execute var_dump($fields); ?

Answer (score 1):

Test this. before sending to PHP change your jsonObj to string.

```js
jsonObj{..}

jsonObj2=JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:"Methods.php",
   data : { 'Json_data':jsonObj2},
   success: function(response) {
    console.log("Result:" + response);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't check if its `NULL`.

```
<? $fields = json_decode($this->item->extra_fields); 
$allowed_fields= array('3','5');  
if($fields) {
foreach ( $fields as $field ) { 
if ( in_array($field->id, $allowed_fields ) && $field->value != NULL) {  
?>
<span class = "list_for<? echo $field->id; ?>">
<? echo $field->value;?></span><? }   } }?>
```

Try `if($fields) {`

You get true if he can decode the json string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$fields = json_decode($this->item->extra_fields); 
$allowed_fields= array('3','5');  
if ( !empty($fields) ) { 
  foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) { 
    if ( in_array($field->id, $allowed_fields ) && !empty($field->value)) {  
   ?>
      <span class = "list_for<?php echo $field->id; ?>">
      <?php echo $field->value;?></span>
  <?php 
  }   
 } 
} 
?>
```

Please copy paste this code and check that error remove or not.
You can't check the $fields with NULL.So you have to check it only by using !empty($fields)